# How to find Document of popup window in AddIns(BHO)?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I am new to fairly new to html. I have got an assignment in which i have stucked from a long time. I have an html page in which popup window opens up on a click of drop down ,which loads an another html page in it. Now using htmlPopup interface how can i get the the document object of that html page loaded in  the popup.

Following is the code for creating popup:

```
IHTMLWindow4 parentWindow = ID2.parentWindow as IHTMLWindow4;
object argIn = Type.Missing;
IHTMLPopup pop = (IHTMLPopup)parentWindow.createPopup(ref argIn);

IHTMLDocument IhtmlDoc = pop.document as IHTMLDocument;

IHTMLDocument2 IhtmlDoc2 = IhtmlDoc as IHTMLDocument2;

IHTMLElement IEle = IhtmlDoc2.body;

IEle.innerHTML = "<SELECT class=\"DropDownScreen\" style=\"LEFT: 0px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 450px; WIDTH: 600px\" SelectionSet='promono_Utf8.html' Size=\"5\"> <OPTION value=\"\" selected=\"-1\"></OPTION><OPTION value=\"NF\">एनएफ : कोई फीस</OPTION><OPTION value=\"CF\">सीएफ : क्लोजर शुल्क लागू</OPTION><OPTION value=\"RF\">आरएफ : शुल्क की वापसी</OPTION> </SELECT>";

pop.Show(dispEvent.x, dispEvent.y,100, 100, dispEvent.srcElement);
```

please help me to get the document. Any help would be very helpful for me . Thank You in advance . .